# CakePHP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: cakephp, dreamhost, internal-server-error

i am getting the following error

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@strivemedicare.in
>   and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
We use DreamHost and the link to the URL is http://strivemedicare.in/
```

Comment: see error log file in cpanel

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There can be following reasons for `500 Internal Server Error` in CakePHP application:

1. Your .htaccess files are not correct. [See Here for details](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html)
2. Permissions of folders are not correct. If CakePHP app is Group Writable i.e. `777` then webserver gives `500` error for safety.
3. You are missing Database Connection. Correct database configuration according to Webhost because most of times local and production server databases have different details.
4. Delete the content of your `tmp` folder. It is best practice that you must delete cache if you move your application from one place to another.
5. For testing purpose debug should be on like `Configure::write('debug',2);`
6. If not succeeded check your Apache Error Log. If using Linux `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Hope It Helps, Thanks!!

Comment: @Love Opensource i following your step. but not success i got same error please help.

Comment: Check your Apache Error Log. If using Linux  /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 2):

Just enable 'mbstring' and 'intl' modules in your host panel.

Answer (score 1):

You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP.
You are getting error in /var/www/html/config/bootstrap.php on line 38

Answer (score 0):

check that when you assign Auth in your `$components` in `AppController`, define

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    //$this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->allow('index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS server I usually fix this issue by using `chmod -R 755 public_html` from current cPanel user directroy.

For example:

```
 chmod -R 755 /home/{cp_username}/public_html/
```

There is also alternative method doing this via cPanel GUI:

[image]