# Subdomain pointed to controller - htaccess (CakePHP?)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect, subdomain

I was looking for quite a while but I couldn't come up with right solution to my problem which seemed to be quite easy at first.

So I got a website based on CakePHP and I want to point some sub domains to matching controllers. For example:

1. hello.domain.com pointed to StaticPages/hello/ *(no redirection; please note that it's not a physical directory)*
2. hello.domain.com/(.*) *redirected* to domain.com/(.*) *(with redirection)*

Here's CakePHP's standard .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Could you help me guys with that? I really got stuck on that.

Thanks in advice,
Mike

-- Edit:

I finally managed with some help to get following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/StaticPages/hello/$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /StaticPages/hello/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L]
```

However I got 500 error, as I suppose because I've created an infinite loop when requesting sub.domain.com/StaticPages/hello/

Do you perhaps have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: 500 error means a general error -- often in your code.  I think usually there will be a specific error if you have a redirect loop.  See this answer regarding 500 errors:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242863/cakephp-500-internal-server-error

Comment: Yeah I know that, but it's not my point here anyway. I know why I got that error but don't know how to solve my problem any other way, not causing it.